# How can I configure AOP in Liferay Service Builder?

Tags: liferay, aop

I want to to intercept a method in Service Builder, for example: `XXXLocalService.update()`. But I don't know the correct way to do this. I have done some research but I haven't found a clear way to do this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways to achieve this in Liferay, assuming you want to intercept Liferay's services:

1. [Service Wrapper Hooks](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-a-portal-service-using-a-hook)

   What this does is gives you a wrapper around the desired service, for eg: `UserLocalServiceWrapper` would be a wrapper around `UserLocalService` and would have complete control over the methods defined in this interface. And this is a good approach if you know the exact method you want to modify/intercept in that particular service.

   Also with this approach you have full control whether the original method should run or not.

   The link provides the full detailed tutorial how to achieve this.
2. [Model Listener Hooks](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-model-listeners)

   This hook should be used when you want to track any changes on the particular Model like in the above case `User` and this is helpful when you are not sure which method is going to update the model.

   What this basically does is gives you a set of methods like `onBeforeUpdate`, `onAfterUpdate`, `onAfterCreate` etc to have control over the model.

   Also this approach would work good enough for your custom services as well.